# How to send post request through Angular to ASP.net web API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

I am new to both angular and ASP.NET web API. in angular i get values from a form and try to pass it to the server through post request her is the code for angular.

```
app.controller('AddTrnController',['$scope', 'CategoriesService','$http', function($scope, CategoriesService, $http){
    $scope.categories =[{}];
    $scope.AddTrn = {};
    function init(){
            CategoriesService.getCategories("1")
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.categories = data;
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers){alert(status);});
        }
    init();

    $scope.change= function(option){
        $scope.AddTrn.TrnID = option.CatID;
        $scope.AddTrn.TrnAccount = 1;
    };


    $scope.UpdateTrans=function(){
        alert("21312");
        $http({method:"post",
            url:'http://localhost:18678/api/Transaction',
            params:"data:$scope.AddTrn"}
            ).success(function(){alert("succeeded");
        }).error(function(){alert("faild");});
    };

}]);
```

And her the the code for web API.

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostTransaction(String transaction)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, transaction);
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = transaction}));
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
```

I always get failed response from angler and when i make breakpoint in API it dose not trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params option that you are using adds items to the query string, for a post you will probably want to use the data option instead, try changing the code to this:

```
$scope.UpdateTrans=function(){
        alert("21312");
        $http({method:"post",
                url:'http://localhost:18678/api/Transaction',
                data:$scope.AddTrn
              }
            ).success(function(){alert("succeeded");
        }).error(function(){alert("faild");});
    };
```

Comment: I am trying both of them and i get the same result

Comment: @user2918388 can you use developer tools in your browser, and go to the network tab, and paste the response you are getting from the request?  If you tell me what browser you are using I can tell you how to get there

Comment: Hit 'f12' to open the developer toolbar and then click the 'Network' tab (should be between the 'Elements' and 'Sources' tabs, ) and then issue the request to the api.  Once you click on the request to the api there should be a 'Response' tab that will have the info that would help

Comment: {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: entity","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentNullException"

Comment: i am sure that the object i send contain data as i can alert it